# facebook api in blackberry

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hello friends I am using blackberry facebook sdk but that is not working properly. When I use 
their skd that is going right but when I create other file and call api them I have face the problem. Please help me. thanks.

Comment: We need more information to being able to help you. Show us some examples of what you are trying to achieve and what your results are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was face same problem when i was tried to use one feature of local image posting on friends wall,but i resolved it using :

Download graph api from http://sourceforge.net/projects/facebook-bb-sdk/. After that i added two thinks.

one was when i wont to post a photo to your friends wall ,you had to put one more key-value in the JSONObject(Request) - that was requestObject.put("target_id",getid()) in publisePhoto method facebookuser.java & facebook.java

Second was, i had to change JSONObject responseObject = fb.write(getId() + "/photos", requestObject, pPhoto.getMIMEType(), imageData, true);

to

JSONObject responseObject = fb.write(getId() + "/photos?access_token="+Facebook.token, requestObject, pPhoto.getMIMEType(), imageData, true);in FacebookUser.java & Facebook.java

where token is Static string from Facebook.java and store the value of access_token (you have to add it)

I hope that will be helpful to you(Little bit).

Comment: Very nice Himanshu. I am Really appreciate you. Very nice solution. I am wondering for that since many times, googled so much but now i find the answer how to upload photo to other firiends wall. The API does not provide any help or suggestion for that.

Thanks so much.